# ggplot2 name space issues

Tags: r, ggplot2

So I was reading [this paper](http://elife.elifesciences.org/content/2/e00638.full-text.pdf), about how regressing x on y doesn't give you an equivalent line to regressing y~x (long story short, you are minimizing different residuals in each case), and I thought I'd see if if made any difference to my data. Unfortunately I can't get ggplot2's stat_smooth to regress x on y.

here is a sample of 100 rows from my data:

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(Sample1 = c(4.98960685567417, 3.47204999768371, 
-1.02623042506767, -3.32192809488736, 4.92376518190495, 5.18057364383907, 
3.37344268231229, 7.17221940674516, -1.53797027495265, 4.59078735278587, 
-3.32192809488736, 4.13323387842297, -3.32192809488736, 1.55320685650568, 
3.45928530433997, 6.52941436696241, 0.291721646202104, 1.34692630168789, 
2.588263571484, 7.93984265473926, -1.02623042506767, -3.32192809488736, 
5.97393529545249, 4.96272548511184, -3.32192809488736, 3.19245860152084, 
-0.181177668537811, 1.1702151401323, 7.19741957077731, -3.32192809488736, 
3.09679962523049, 6.89612648849508, 4.49710160528899, 2.90303096540262, 
2.44022334122376, 4.53409217014818, 4.7590708357255, 4.72481633684295, 
0.691615956272056, 3.49724548154186, 3.31795986458613, 5.83755830779617, 
4.36304299927157, -0.0295430166578704, 5.02251917128349, 7.38120720286448, 
2.00357119131309, 3.28216732938001, 4.78231786359764, -0.764299371525642, 
3.92619319211129, 0.0406883788967327, 2.85511116340049, 5.66764040870341, 
1.5770354481397, 6.94329764296121, 3.9308239558015, 5.74724483501107, 
5.88247371232242, 3.60547757169518, -3.32192809488736, -0.542695575918393, 
5.28191680995643, 2.77496647475118, -1.34650507208309, -2.74783703944563, 
6.41591061993452, 3.7539739823111, 2.49127670210767, 6.65016370221803, 
6.32032425410637, -3.32192809488736, 0.402556327534611, 2.34628748804301, 
0.89488462084739, 1.1702151401323, -3.32192809488736, 4.72748036766425, 
5.61681844161155, 2.03831731682591, -0.443475473403791, -2.74783703944563, 
-3.32192809488736, 4.10482914538061, 5.3663866285164, 2.15373368651261, 
-3.32192809488736, 5.45745992658215, -0.764299371525642, 1.69060972560112, 
0.171658206055067, 4.46553470954628, 4.93993527938277, 2.23086351589855, 
0.2329385503416, 6.14110973873979, -0.443475473403791, -3.32192809488736, 
4.16502606126426, 5.45906373012262), Sample2 = c(4.87035389289972, 
3.05631305243025, 0.82323632916493, -2.4296633454796, 4.91811337313532, 
5.03007694504678, 3.33859900165761, 6.54820168349871, -2.4296633454796, 
4.86188407042978, -3.32192809488736, 4.62717002820498, -1.67106299528127, 
-3.32192809488736, 2.98790308889454, 6.05226752694174, 0.596977520519267, 
1.99826710332906, 2.23966464285132, 8.01717854320643, -0.00159952300352469, 
-1.48670630366969, 5.43594909921552, 4.95640818811881, -3.32192809488736, 
4.90168009665292, 0.555561013584398, 2.27836717662796, 6.47511546712932, 
-3.32192809488736, 3.01870866264235, 2.08814992134377, 3.65522335205242, 
3.36281234142216, 1.68917367193269, 3.90649842473784, 4.95242469001903, 
4.78780929337046, 3.21768687367553, 3.85621590296538, 3.41005295130021, 
5.53250156756501, 3.7175760684724, 0.676405696816667, 5.14971539956163, 
6.98398467911331, 3.3567969981478, 3.88157621603906, 4.90168009665292, 
-0.0647853872737311, 4.55018561922281, 1.21774415322831, 2.60706104004096, 
5.87421631057342, 2.22652958465421, 7.02865467720292, 3.39838702576746, 
5.19424993242169, 5.32786325515541, 2.67632233586628, -2.80788789937207, 
0.172877949731557, 4.84264318258294, 2.7144567398541, -0.00159952300352469, 
-1.17646253367489, 6.33756586506636, 3.68433673855881, 2.62719159116047, 
6.51076754571708, 6.31214443849056, -1.88247779017497, 0.714537926272974, 
3.17045554987033, 0.32851270527504, 9.05953630113146, -2.80788789937207, 
4.36480327392371, 5.88366056411048, 1.63054822649657, 2.01364185790907, 
-1.04323142745032, -2.80788789937207, 2.88298417549747, 5.60661313436485, 
1.9024101424183, -0.516096487844633, 5.42017137768702, -0.921270583844273, 
2.36482913745982, 2.46888455306976, 4.55807157102875, 5.01105219152827, 
1.19094552584428, 0.987970258058337, 5.55106017924769, 2.15899824583894, 
-3.32192809488736, 3.92287721859118, 5.06185416274169)), .Names = c("Sample1", 
"Sample2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -100L))
```

When I try to plot using ggplot2, I can easy put the regression y on x on the plot:

```
> ggplot(df, aes(x=Sample1,y=Sample2)) + geom_point() + stat_smooth(formula = y~x, method = "lm")
```

But if I try to use anything else in the formula I get a can't find object error:

```
> ggplot(df, aes(x=Sample1,y=Sample2)) + geom_point() + stat_smooth(formula = y~x, method = "lm") +  stat_smooth(formula = x~y, method = "lm")
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'y' not found
```

I tried using the original column names (Sample1 and Sample2) instead of x and y, and giving the `stat_smooth` its own aes, all gave the same error.

I assume this is a name space error: the formula is being evaluated in the wrong environment somehow, but I don't know why one works but not the other, or how to fix the problem.

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: Ian, do you think you might un-accept James' answer? It isn't doing what any of us thought. The second line representing the inverse regression model is plotting in a coordinate system that is not what is shown on the plot. Hence the two regression lines don't cross at / pass through the bivariate mean (well one does, but not the inverse line).

Comment: Oops, sorry, I just ran it and saw that it gave what looked to be correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to think about what `stat_smooth(formula = x~y, method = "lm")` is doing in the context of the plot you are trying to draw.

The error is most likely arising because when `formula` is evaluated in the formula parsing code, the variable named on the right hand side of `~` (`y` in the error case) is **not** in the set of data defined internally by **ggplot** as corresponding to the x-axis of the plot. `ggplot` must isolate the `x` variable data and only look up variables from that data object.

Now back to thinking about your plot. You drew a plot with `x` on the x-axis and `y` on the y-axis. The linear model of `x ~ y` has the data vectors on the opposite "axes". So from the grammar point of view, the definition you gave doesn't make sense. I think what I am trying to say is that the right hand side of the formula can only contain `x` or functions of `x`, as that is all that is available internally.

If you want to do this, add the regression line for `x ~ y` yourself, something like:

```
mod <- lm(Sample1 ~ Sample2, data = df)
pdat <- with(df, data.frame(Sample2= seq(min(Sample2), max(Sample2), 
                                         length = 100)))
pdat <- transform(pdat, Sample1 = predict(mod, newdata = pdat))

ggplot(df, aes(x=Sample1,y=Sample2)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  stat_smooth(formula = y~x, method = "lm") +
  geom_line(data = pdat, aes(x = Sample1, y = Sample2))
```

You could add the confidence interval using `geom_ribbon()` and compute it by using the `interval = "confidence"` argument to `predict.lm`. You'll need to modify the

```
pdat <- transform(pdat, Sample1 = predict(mod, newdata = pdat))
```

to accommodate this, but that is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: I've restored the answer now. I was initially a little concerned that it might not be returning what was expected, so that's why I deleted it. +1 for your detailed explanation of what's happening.

Comment: And now rolled back so James can have his rightful glory! :-)

Answer (score 2):

A work-around is to use another `aes()` call in the smoother call to switch around `x` and `y`:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=Sample1,y=Sample2)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    stat_smooth(method="lm") + 
    stat_smooth(aes(x=Sample2,y=Sample1), method="lm")
```

Comment: @GavinSimpson Hmm, I suspected the co-ordinates were flipped in the output. Is there any way to perform `coord_flip()` on a single element?

Comment: Actually it seems this is wrong after all - it is plotting the lines in the wrong coordinate space. You can see that the lines don't cross at the bivariate mean of the data, a coordinate that is invariant to the change in role of the two variables in the regression. Sorry for the confusion. I should have checked your Answer more thoroughly earlier before encouraging that it be reopened.